# MKAnnotationMethod animatesDrop not working

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation

I have made it so that the UILongPressGestureRecognizer drops a pin, but I want it to be animated. So I try and set the animatesDrop property in the press: method, and I do not get any errors, but it is not working. I do not know if I set the property in the wrong place, or what.

Here is the code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self
                                                                                       action:@selector(press:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
[longPress setDelegate:self];
[worldView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

}

```
-(void)press:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:worldView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [worldView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:worldView];

if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == recognizer.state) {
    BNRMapPoint *mp = [[BNRMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate
                                                       title:@"Some Title"];
    [worldView addAnnotation:mp];
    [mp setAnimatesDrop:YES];
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setAnimatesDrop:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008203-CH1-SW5) is a method of MKPinAnnotationView, while your `BNRMapPoint` seems like annotation class implementing the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

You need to provide `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method to return an MKPinAnnotationView for your annotation, where you can set MKPinAnnotationView's `animatesDrop` property to `YES`.

You can refer to Apple's sample code [MapCallouts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I tried implementing the mapView:viewForAnnotation method, but it replaces the currentLocation with a pin. How do I keep the current location without dropping a pin on the current location?

Comment: I tried changing the BNRMapPoint to be a subclass of MKPinAnnotationView, and set the animatesDrop property to YES. But it is still not working.